# Tomcat shuts down unexpectidly

Tags: linux, tomcat, memory, java

I am using Apache Tomcat 8.0.23 with 1 GB RAM on centos 6 OS . I have used servlet and jsp for server side . But after few days it shuts down automatically . I have given memory size as `CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms128M -Xmx256M"` at bin/setenv.sh . Can anybody tell me why my server shuts down ? I am not much familiar with Tomcat and linux . I also tried to see log files at `var/log`  and `apache-Tomcat/logs` . But i did not find any suspicious thing there. Is 1 GB RAM enough for my server ?. My android application is running on near about 5000 devices .

Any suggestions ?

Edit :

```
07-Aug-2015 03:58:03.199 INFO [Finalizer] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.net.BindException]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.net.BindException]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1327)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1196)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException.<init>(CommunicationsException.java:161)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2759)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:1410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.realClose(Connection.java:4900)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.cleanup(Connection.java:2061)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.finalize(Connection.java:3376)
    at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(System.java:1270)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:98)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:34)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:210)

10-Aug-2015 18:34:35.757 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-63] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "root"
10-Aug-2015 18:36:19.397 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-65] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "manager"
10-Aug-2015 18:36:28.451 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-63] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "manager"
10-Aug-2015 18:36:38.882 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-70] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "manager"
```

Thanks !

Comment: "But after few days it shuts down automatically" - maybe if you showed us the logs leading up to a shutdown we might be able to hazard a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible to point out an exact cause with just the context given in the question. You'll need to gather more information about it to point out any root cause.

I can only offer you general heuristics to debug it. Try to change various parameters of the environment to localize the root cause, changing only one thing at a time.
When does the problem occur? Does it happen under certain application load. What happens if you run the instance of tomcat without your application in it? Does it work on another OS or machine?

You'll need to start isolating the fault. If it runs fine on another machine the you can rule out the environmental causes such as a cron job or some system service killing the process. If your tomcat instance runs fine without the application then the fault is not in server configuration. And so on.

To speed up the process (since it only reoccurs every few days) you could run each of your test in a separate tomcat instance and thus concurrently test for multiple possibilities.

To me memory doesn't seem to be the issue here. The memory allocated should be sufficient but even if it isn't you should be getting `OutOfMemoryError` not just silent arbitrary shutdowns.

You can try increasing the verbosity of tomcat logging to print more detailed information. This can be done by changing settings under `./conf/logging.properties`

Comment: Is it fine to use servlets and jsp without using any framework in respect of closing database connections , Garbage colletion etc . @Kshitiz

Comment: @DeepakRathore A database exception should not shut down the container. Its fine to use vanilla servlets without using any MVC framework if your use case calls for it. Its hard to tell what's going on without any details. Consider adding your logs to this question via pastebin or dropbox. In particular `catalina.out` might hold some clues.

Comment: Thanks for support . I'll  try to  get more info of this problem . Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing memory and then edit the setenv.sh file and increase the CATALINA_OPTS variables to allocate more memory to tomcat.